# Group repeated values by GROUP_BY with counter?

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL, and currently my query returns something like:

```
|ID|Tags|
|01|tag1,tag2,tag2,tag2
|02|tag2,tag2
|03|tag2,tag2,tag2,tag2,tag3
```

I'd like it to return:

```
|ID|Tags|
|01|tag1,tag2(x3)
|02|tag2(x2)
|03|tag2(x4),tag3
```

The repeated values are expected. All I want is to group them. Is it even possible?

I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT(table.column)`, and it returns me those results.

Comment: can you give some sample data and the query youre using?

Comment: My query is this: http://pastebin.com/kmieFXgt It is pretty much self-explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I made a solution.. I had to play with it for a little bit... but basically you have to do a pretty nasty looking query to get this to work. if you can do this in another programming language it would be best.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(final_tags) 
FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM(
    SELECT 
      tag, 
      combined, 
      IF(tag <> combined, CONCAT(tag, combined), tag) AS final_tags,
      counted, 
      id 
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        id,
        tag,
        IF(@A = tag, @B := @COUNTER, @B := 1) AS counted,
        IF(@A = tag, @D := CONCAT('(x', @COUNTER, ')'), @D := tag) AS combined,
        @A := tag,
        IF(@B = 1, @COUNTER := 1, @COUNTER),
        @COUNTER := @COUNTER + 1
      FROM myTable
      JOIN (SELECT @A := '', @D := '', @COUNTER := 1, @B := 0) AS t
      ) AS temp
    ORDER BY counted DESC
    ) AS whatever
  GROUP BY tag
) AS this_is_it
GROUP BY id
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb225/1) for clarification

Comment: Flawless! I'm forced to use SQL only, but I will indeed use another language as soon as I'm able to. By the way, could you please explain what `:=` and `@` do?

Comment: you will have to put this into your query because I don't have sample data to work with... so to join the other tables, join them where I do the join(select @A.. etc... join next to that join and pull out the correct tag and stuff and itll work

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html for info on `@` and `:=`

Comment: ah gotcha.. I was assuming that you were considering the question... so the `@` is a way to make a user defined variable.. so I make a few to do some calculations and use them to figure out how many repeats of tags we have and stuff of that nature.. the `:=` is how you assign a value to that variable... = is used for comparison and := is for assignment :)